# how to update jinja2 html_params from field only when field error

Tags: flask, jinja2, wtforms

i have implementation of custome template for flask-security-too using bs4.
The flow is when user login and wrong email/password, i will display invalid-feedback to user. I have implement macro for every field, this is my sc:

**login_form.html**

```
{% extends "security/layout.html" %}
{% from "security/macro/auth_message.html" import auth_message as am %}
{% from "security/macro/forms.html" import render_field_with_errors, render_field, render_field_errors,
render_field_with_errors_no_labels, render_field_with_errors_no_labels_without_input_group %}
{% block title %}{{ 'login page' | title }}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
{{ am("Login Form") }}
{% include "security/macro/alert.html" %}
<form class="form-signin" action="{{ url_for_security('login') }}" method="POST" name="login_user_form">
    {{ login_user_form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ render_field_with_errors_no_labels(login_user_form.email, class_="form-control", id="email", placeholder="Email
    address") }}
    {{ render_field_with_errors_no_labels(login_user_form.password,class_="form-control", id="password",
    placeholder="Password") }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="icheck-primary">
                {{ render_field_with_errors_no_labels_without_input_group(login_user_form.remember, id="remember") }}
                <label for="remember">
                    Remember Me
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-4">
            {{ render_field(login_user_form.submit,class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ) }}
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
    <hr>
    {{ render_field_errors(login_user_form.csrf_token) }}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**security/macro/forms.html**

```
{% macro render_field_with_errors_no_labels(field) %}
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    {{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
    {% if field.errors %}
    {# this section i have trouble #}
    {% set field = field.html_params({'class_':'is-invalid', 'aria-describedby':'{{ field.id }}-error'}) %}
    <span id="{{ field.id }}-error" class="invalid-feedback">
        {% for error in field.errors %}
        {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
    </span>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

but the result is

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'wtforms.fields.simple.PasswordField object' has no attribute 'html_params'
```

so, how to update field with **kwargs to add spesified class and atribute ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have done with this issue, basic solving after read wtforms documentation [here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/specific_problems/#rendering-errors)

this is my revision code

**security/macro/forms.html**

```
{% macro render_field_with_errors_no_labels(field) %}
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    {% if field.errors %}
    {% set update_aria = kwargs.update({'aria_describedby': field.id~'-error'}) %}
    {% set update_css = kwargs.update({'class' :'form-control is-invalid'}) %}
    {{ field(class=update_class, aria_describedby=update_aria, **kwargs) }}
    <span id="{{ field.id }}-error" class="invalid-feedback">
        {% for error in field.errors %}
        {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
    </span>
    {% else %}
    {{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endmacro %}
```